# Heat sink via holes under voltage regulator LM2596

Tags: power, pcb, eaglecad

I am designing a board with LM2596 voltage regulator (12V/5V 3A)

[image]

I want to make heat-removing holes under the microcircuit. For this, I decided to use via holes. The board has two layers.
The question is, is this the right solution? Or do they do the heat sink differently?

[image]

UPD.

[image]

Comment: Unrelated to the heatsink question, but considering that this is a switching regulator I would consider redoing the layout with planes/polygons instead of traces (especially long thin traces). Look into reference designs and eval kits for examples.

Comment: Typically, the entire underside of the board would be one large ground plane. If you then use a bunch of via's underneath the chip it would act as both heatsink and a beefy low inductance ground connection. I'd also move the flywheel diode as close as possible to the output pin of the chip, use wider traces (polygons), add ceramic capacitance to the output and and take the feedback from the output capacitor in stead of from the inductor (see figure 32 in datasheet).

Comment: Also what are your goals for Tj max, Pd max , thus Rca max then SMD vs THT and did you look at ON Semi & TI land patterns?  Can you ensure solder fill to entire area ? no

Comment: @Unimportant, As a scheme, I used recommendations from Texas Instruments. Unfortunately, there was no mention of the output ceramic capacitor on the 5V line. Can you tell me which face value to choose? http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2596.pdf

Comment: @WesleyLee, I had doubts about the correct layout, now I'm starting to change it for sure.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist, 
I do it for the first time, do not quite understand what is being said.

Comment: Is the location of the diode and inductor better than the previous one? I have not forgotten about the rectangles. About the width of the contacts - here the width is 8128. The weight of copper is 2 ounces. As I understand it, with this weight the width of the track decreases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each empty via (not solder-filled), if depth/periphery ratio is one:one and thus we can model the metal inside the via as a square of copper (plated) of proportion 1:1, and the plated copper is 35 microns (1.4 mils), the standard thickness of  foil that is 1 ounce/foot^2 weight, has a THERMAL RESISTANCE of 70 degree Centigrade per watt of heat flow. And you need to let that heat spread out, on the backside of the PCB, or be taken to metal frame or case or chassis.

You have 4*5 vias in parallel, or about 70/20 = 3.5 degree C per watt, **BUT** all those 20 vias are transferring heat into the **SAME** tiny region of the back layer of foil.

You need a way to remove the heat from the 20 vias, but you have no way to remove the heat.

If you do add lots of backside foil, each square of foil offers the previously-mentioned 70 degree Centigrade per watt of thermal resistance.

Like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBR7ku.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The thermal resistance of that first 3*3 ring of squares, around the central heat source, the 8 total squares in that ring, produce 70degreeC/8 = 9 degree Centigrade per watt of heat flow.

Each larger ring of squares (each square being 3:1 larger) also adds 9 degree Centigrade per watt.